# Clean Eclipse 3.8.1 cache

Tags: eclipse

I want to clean Eclipse's 3.8.1 cache using Eclipses's GUI and not using the CLI.

I'm using Ubuntu.  How could I do this?

I can not find an answer for the version of Eclipse I am using.

Comment: What do you mean by cache? What part of Eclipse are you trying to "clean?"

Comment: I mean by cache, cache memory

Comment: Memory of what? Specific questions get the best answers. To put it another way, describe what end-goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: When I run my code it shows an old version of it, so I imagine it gets it from the Eclipse's cache, just like a browser's cache

Comment: Nope, that's not at all true. If Eclipse did that it wouldn't be a very good IDE :-)  There must be something else going on in the way you are launching your program. I suggest you close this and open a new question with the details.

Comment: Then, why I get an old version of my code? Where does it take from?